# ListBoxes won't display data from StreamReader text files

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have the .txt files inside the project's debug folder but the listboxes still won't display any of the data.

I've already missed the due date for this project, I just have a very unhelpful professor and I'd love to learn what I did wrong. Thanks!

The overview of what I'm trying to do here is:

Display delimited data into three listboxes from three text files. When a user clicks on an item in the listbox, one line of additional data (an ID) will be displayed in a textbox underneath that listbox. All three listboxes are shown on the same form and all data is delimited using the same character.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;


namespace LabDay2Modified
{

    struct CustomersNames
    {
        public string custID;
        public string firstName;
        public string lastName;
        public string accountID;
    }

    struct AccountNumbers
    {
        public string acctID;
        public string accountType;
        public string accountNumber;
        public string accountAmt;
    }

    struct LoanInfo
    {
        public string loanID;
        public string loanYears;
        public string loanIntRate;
        public string loanAmt;
        public string customerID;
        public string loanType;
    }

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private List<CustomersNames> customerList = new List<CustomersNames>();
        private List<AccountNumbers> accountList = new List<AccountNumbers>();
        private List<LoanInfo> loanList = new List<LoanInfo>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ReadCustFile()
        {
            try
            {
                StreamReader inputFile;
                string line;

                CustomersNames entry = new CustomersNames();

                char[] delim = { ',' };

                inputFile = File.OpenText("customers.txt");

                while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
                {
                    line = inputFile.ReadLine();

                    string[] tokens = line.Split(delim);

                    entry.custID = tokens[0];
                    entry.firstName = tokens[1];
                    entry.lastName = tokens[2];
                    entry.accountID = tokens[3];

                    customerList.Add(entry);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void ReadAcctFile()
        {
            try
            {
                StreamReader inputFile;
                string line;

                AccountNumbers entry = new AccountNumbers();

                char[] delim = { ',' };

                inputFile = File.OpenText("accounts.txt");

                while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
                {
                    line = inputFile.ReadLine();

                    string[] tokens = line.Split(delim);

                    entry.acctID = tokens[0];
                    entry.accountNumber = tokens[1];
                    entry.accountType = tokens[2];
                    entry.accountAmt = tokens[3];

                    accountList.Add(entry);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void ReadLoanFile()
        {
            try
            {
                StreamReader inputFile;
                string line;

                LoanInfo entry = new LoanInfo();

                char[] delim = { ',' };

                inputFile = File.OpenText("loans.txt");

                while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
                {
                    line = inputFile.ReadLine();

                    string[] tokens = line.Split(delim);

                    entry.customerID = tokens[0];
                    entry.loanID = tokens[1];
                    entry.loanType = tokens[2];
                    entry.loanYears = tokens[3];
                    entry.loanIntRate = tokens[4];
                    entry.loanAmt = tokens[5];

                    loanList.Add(entry);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void CustInfo()
        {
            foreach(CustomersNames entry in customerList)
            {
                customerListBox.Items.Add(entry.custID + " " + entry.firstName + " " + entry.lastName);
            }
        }

        private void AcctInfo()
        {
            foreach (AccountNumbers entry in accountList)
            {
                accountListBox.Items.Add(entry.accountNumber + " " + entry.accountType + " " + entry.accountAmt);
            }
        }

        private void LoansInfo()
        {
            foreach (LoanInfo entry in loanList)
            {
                loanListBox.Items.Add(entry.loanID + " " + entry.loanType + " " + entry.loanYears+" "+entry.loanIntRate+" "+entry.loanAmt);
            }
        }



        private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void customerListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int index = customerListBox.SelectedIndex;
            customerAccountID.Text = "Account ID: " + customerList[index].accountID;
        }

        private void loanListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int index = loanListBox.SelectedIndex;
            loanCustomerID.Text = "Customer ID: " + loanList[index].customerID;
        }

        private void accountListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int index = accountListBox.SelectedIndex;
            accountAccountID.Text = "Account ID: " + accountList[index].acctID;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReadCustFile();
            CustInfo();

            ReadAcctFile();
            AcctInfo();

            ReadLoanFile();
            LoansInfo();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: [Tagging help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging): _"The only time you should use tags in your title is when they are organic to the conversational tone of the title."_ [`[visual-studio]` tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/visual-studio/info): _"DO NOT use this tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio"_

Comment: `entry = new CustomersNames();` this needs to be done inside while loop.  For all three file loading functions

Comment: I have tested the code you provided, but I could show the data in the listbox. I guess that it may be related to your txt file. can you provide the txt file?

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT  Here are the text files:

customers.txt
1,Ann,Porter,5
2,William,Porter,5
3,Daniel,Higgins,2
4,Mary,Langan,2
5,Luis,Delgado,3
6,Kelly,Stratman,4
7,Gerry,Yates,1
8,Greta,Mickel,1
9,James,Podell,6
10,Emily,Lowe,6

accounts.txt
1,1234,1,950.25
2,2345,2,100.5
3,3456,2,3452.23
4,4567,1,1500
5,5678,1,602.75
6,6789,2,5000


loans.txt
1,1,1,30,3.75,200000
2,2,2, 3,0.90,10000
4,3,2, 5,1.90,30000
3,4,1,30,4.00,300000
6,5,1,15,3.50,100000
7,6,2, 5,1.90,15000
5,7,2, 5,1.90,18000
9,8,1,30,4.20,270000

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following .txt file to see if it works for you.

[image]

Then, you will get the following result.

[image]

Besides, you can set the similar style for other txt files.